# How to migrate multi-account Thunderbird profile from Mac to Windows?

Tags: windows, mac, email, thunderbird

I use Thunderbird 60.6.1 on macOS 10.14. I have 9 email accounts with about 20 email identities between them. I would like to copy all these to a Thunderbird profile in a Windows 10 VM that I'm running on the same machine. How can I do this?

I have tried copying the contents of my `~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/<whatever>.default` profile directory over to the `%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Thunderbird/Profiles/<whatever>.default` on the Windows VM. It kind of works, in that mail appears there and I can log in to my mail server, but only 1 of my 9 email accounts shows up on the receiving end.

I have tried doing the transfer both with a .zip file of my profile that I transferred over using Dropbox and VMware shared folders, and a FAT-formatted USB drive that I first attached to the Mac side and then the Windows side. Same results with both procedures: only one (my primary) email account shows up on the receiving Windows side.

Any ideas?

Comment: Was Thunderbird closed when you copied the profile?  Were you logged into macOS when you copied it?

Comment: Thunderbird was closed, and i was logged in to macOS.

Answer (score 2):

I was copying it to the wrong location: the profile data needs to go in `%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Roaming`, not `%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local`.